# Skip synchronous script execution if the script hasn't been downloaded

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page with two inline script (they both can't be run async).
I can control the page (and to add `setTimeout()` for example) and I can control and change these two scripts.
I can't rely on the fact that the second script will be downloaded fast enough (because of some issues with the CDN this script is using) and because the second script run synchronously as well - I have a problem.

```
<head>
    <script src="my_first_script.js"></script>
    <script src="my_second_script.js"></script>
</head>
```

If the second script hasn't **been downloaded** in 2 seconds - I want to run the page without waiting for this script.
The two scripts must be inline scripts (we can't use document.write for this).

I also checked adding preload:

```
<head>
    <link rel="preload" href="main.js" as="script">
    <script src="my_first_script.js"></script>
    <script src="my_second_script.js"></script>
</head>
```

So, when the execution of my_first_script will be done, I will already have a link object and the downloaded will be in process / done.

Do you have an idea how to skip the waiting for my_second_script if 2 seconds already passed? Thanks!

Comment: Better to change your page so that it doesn't depend on the synchronous downloading of `my_second_script`, and then you can handle it properly at the end of DOM loading, else I don't think it's possible

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks for your suggestion, as I wrote the script MUST run synchronously. 


@johnSmith - one time our CDN (one of its nodes) didn't respond at all (not 404), but because we talk here on a synchronous script - the page was stuck... and waited for `my_second_script` till the page ended with a timeout.

Comment: If the script has to run synchronously, *and* its download is uncertain, then your design is flawed, and should be changed

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Thanks for pointing this out. Will love to hear suggestions to solve the issue that I have described (if it can be done). I can solve it by using `document.write` instead of inline scripts, but I prefer a solution with no `document.write` in it.

Comment: Sure, can you explain what is depending on `my_second_script` to execute synchronously? General idea would be to move that code to a `Promise.race` callback